# Rollback error in using Spring DBUnit, Spring Data and embedded H2 database

Tags: spring, spring-data, h2, sqlexception, spring-test-dbunit

I've been stuck in a curios error.

I have a small DBUnit Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/testApplicationContext.xml") 
@Category(Integrationtest.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
    })
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:db/wbSchluesselwertData.xml")
public class KontaktrolleRepositoryIntegrationTest {


    @Autowired
    KontaktrolleRepository kontaktrolleRepository;

    @Autowired
    KontaktBeteiligterRepository kontaktBeteiligterRepository;

    @Autowired
    WbSchluesselwertRepository wbSchluesselwertRepository;
........
........
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void that_Kontaktrolle_Is_Inserted_Into_DB() throws Exception {

        WbSchluesselwert wbRolle1 = wbSchluesselwertRepository.findOne(new Long(11)); 

        KontaktBeteiligter b1 = new KontaktBeteiligterBuilderAws(erzeugtAm).withName("Posteingang")
                .withStandort("Cologne").withOrganization("private").build();


        KontaktBeteiligter result = kontaktBeteiligterRepository.save(b1);

        Kontaktrolle r1 = new KontaktrolleBuilder(erzeugtAm).withBeteiligter(result).withRollenartId(wbRolle1).build();

        Kontaktrolle resultRolle = kontaktrolleRepository.save(r1);

        assertNotNull(resultRolle);
        assertNotNull(resultRolle.getKontaktrolleId());
        assertThat(resultRolle.getKontaktrolleId(), greaterThan(0L));

    }
```

Nothing more. First I want to search an entry which is prefilled by DBUnit (wbSchluesselwertData.xml).
And after that I want to save two entries via Spring Data CrudRepository within a embedded H2 memory Database.

This datasource is wrapped by an HibernateJpaVendorAdapter and the adapter itself in a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:

```
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.axa.chronik.persistence.domain" />
</bean>
```

If I run the unit test above I got the following error:

```
21:21:55,808 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:594 - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@f6b9e9] after transaction
21:21:55,808 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:338 - Closing JPA EntityManager
21:21:55,809  WARN TestContextManager:397 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [com.github.springtestdbunit.TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener@4c4b3e] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void de.axa.chronik.persistence.repository.KontaktrolleRepositoryIntegrationTest.that_Kontaktrolle_Is_Inserted_Into_DB() throws java.lang.Exception], instance [de.axa.chronik.persistence.repository.KontaktrolleRepositoryIntegrationTest@be41d5], exception [null]
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:544)...............
...........
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Das Objekt wurde bereits geschlossen
The object is already closed [90007-175]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
```

So the subsequent attempt to persist the entity fails because the connection has been closed.
Are there exsisting effects between hibernate persist and the use ob Spring DBUnit which I disregard?

Any help  is appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bodo

Comment: I get the same error message `JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-195]` in DbUnit test with H2, Spring and Hibernate (JPA). So I suppose the problem is not related to Spring Data.

Comment: If I change `TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class` to `DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class` the error goes away, but database changes are not rolled back after test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `TestExecutionListeners`. This setup worked for me:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
```

There's no `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-175]` error anymore, and my tests are executed inside a transaction now. **BUT** changes made in DbUnit's `@DatabaseSetup` are not rolled back when transaction ends (i.e. after each test case).

Answer (score 0):

As you manually configure the test execution listeners, you need to register the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` as otherwise transactions are not started on the test level. This will cause the transaction already being closed when the repository returns an cause exceptions like the one you see.

Comment: Hmm, unfortuantely I didn't get you answer at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get you answer at all. In my applicationContext I set the JpaTransactionManager whith the property LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
In my testCase above I register the TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class. Instead of this class I could register TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class and DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, but with the same effect.
I could also annotate the test method with Rollback(false) but also this hasn't any effect.
My Memory Database is declared within my testApplicationContext:
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">..

Comment: Changing `TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class` to `TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class` + `DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class` helped to get rid of this error. I can confirm that my tests are executed inside a transaction now. **BUT** changes made in `@DatabaseSetup` are not rolled back when transaction ends (i.e. after each test case).

Comment: This stuff forces me into a state of mental instability... It works only if you register `DbUnitTestExecutionListener` **BEFORE** `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.